# Is Module pattern necessary in this case?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

Last night in a mega bout of insomnia I realised - maybe the module pattern might not be necessary in my case. I have a bunch of "classes" like this:

```
if (typeof MyApp === 'null') MyApp = {};

MyApp.MyClass = function ()
{
    this.func1 = function ()
    {
    }

    this.func2 = function (
    {
    }
}
```

And I've been converting them to the module pattern like this (so they're much the same - just wrapped in a self-executing anonymous function):

```
    if (typeof MyApp === 'null') MyApp = {};

(function (win, doc, null)
{
    MyApp.MyClass = function ()
    {
        this.func1 = function ()
        {
        }

        this.func2 = function (
        {
        }
    }
})(window, document);
```

But since evrything is in the MyApp.MyClass "class" function anyway - it's not really necessary is it? After all the only thing that's exposed is the MyClass variable.

Comment: this is not module pattern: you have just wrapped a function into a self-executing anonimous function

Comment: How is it not the module pattern? From various articles that I read that is the module pattern.